# Recorrer arreglo con ngFor en Angular me retorna [object Object],[object Object]

Tags: javascript, array, angular, objeto, ngfor

Tengo unos datos con esta estructura:

```javascript
data = {
   test: [
     {
       nombre_cv: "test",
       bloque: "Articulos",
       atributo: "titulo",
       visible_cv_personalizado: true
     }
   ],
   convocatoria: [
     {
       nombre_cv: "test",
       bloque: "Articulos",
       atributo: "id",
       visible_cv_personalizado: true
     },
     {
       nombre_cv: "test",
       bloque: "Articulos", 
       atributo: "titulo", 
       visible_cv_personalizado: true
     }
   ]
 }
```

Quiero que se muestre el test y la convocatoria con sus propiedades, para ello uso ngFor de la siguiente forma:

```html
 <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
      Key: <b>{{item.key}},</b> value: <b> {{item.value}} |</b>
 </div>
```

Pero al momento de mostrar en pantalla me retorna esto:

> Key: convocatoria, value: [object Object] | Key: test, value: [object Object],[object Object]

Como pueden ver me retorna la llave, pero las propiedades salen con:

> [object Object],[object Object].

Cómo puedo hacer que me muestre todas las propiedades de test y convocatoria? Agradezco de antemano espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: El problema es que data es un object, compuesto por dos objects. Por lo tanto, si recorres un array de objects, vas a iterar sobre objects en sí, en tu caso, sobre test y convocatoria. Debes hacer el ngFor sobre cada propiedad del array en sí, no sobre el array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dice `Sergio` estas iterando sobre un objeto de arrays. Ahora bien si la estructura que tienes se va a mantener siempre es decir vas a iterar un objeto que contiene arrays puedes hacer lo siguiente según tu código.

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of data">
   <p *ngFor="let itemAux of item | keyvalue">
      Key: <b>{{itemAux.key}},</b> value: <b> {{itemAux.value}} |</b>
   </p>
</div>
```

Donde puedes observar que ahora iteramos internamente a tu variable `item`. Generando un `párrafo` interno, que puede ser cambiado perfectamente por un `div` si lo requieres.